# How to stop() animation but allow current one to complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Using jQuery 1.7.2

```
$(function(){
    $('#parentElem').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.myElem').animate({opacity:1}, 'fast');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.myElem').stop().animate{opacity:0}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

In this example, I have an element that fades in on a `mouseenter` event and then halts and fades out again (on the `mouseout`) to give a throb effect.

I have a problem however - using the `.stop()` method, the currently running animation will be interrupted and fade back out again - my 'throb' effect not really working. Of course this is exactly what `.stop()` is *for* - however what I really want to do is just clear the queue and let the current animation complete, while adding the fade out animation to the queue.

Any ideas?

P.S I've tried the `.clearQueue()` method also but this exhibits similar behaviour.

EDIT:
Something I really should have mentioned - I need the element to stay faded in while the cursor is over it - so using the callback on the animate function wouldn't solve it. I've updated the code to make it more obvious. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [complete callback of the animate method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to perform the fadeOut:

```
$('.myElem').animate({opacity:1}, 'fast', function() {$(this).stop().animate{opacity:0}, 'slow');});
```

**Update**

A similar approach can be used to set a flag to ensure that the animate is stopped and then faded out on the later of the mouseout / fade in complete:

```
(function() {
  var doFadeOut = false;
  var fadeOut = function() {
    if (doFadeOut) {
        $('.myElem').stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 'slow');
        doFadeOut = false;
    } else {
        doFadeOut = true;
    }
  };
  $('#parentElem').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.myElem').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'fast', fadeOut);
  }).mouseleave(fadeOut);
}())
```

Comment: good answer, thanks. I'm slapping myself on the forehead now though because I didn't explain the problem properly - sorry. Please see updated question

Comment: very elegant, thankyou. this worked for me - you're missing an open bracket on the animate in the if test in stopAnimation though :)